# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "int" Position: 22

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here I wanted to insert data in the child table using primary key id of parent table but getting an execution error  ***ERROR: syntax error at or near "int"***

I want to use IndiaCountry variable in Insert query for this task. How can I implement this?

```
CREATE TABLE Countries
(
    id        SERIAL,
    description VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT coutry_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE Cities
(
      country_code_id  int,
      city_id     int,
      description   VARCHAR(100),
      CONSTRAINT cities_pkey PRIMARY KEY (city_id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_cities_countries FOREIGN KEY  (country_code_id) REFERENCES Countries (id)
);






INSERT INTO COUNTRIES (description) VALUES('asdf');
DECLARE indiaCountry int;
@indiaCountry =  'SELECT id FROM COUNTRIES WHERE description = 'asdf';'
INSERT INTO cities VALUES (@indiaCountry, 1 , 'abc');
```

Comment: You are declaring indiaCountry as integer, and then asigning it a string ...

Comment: still giving the same error

Comment: I am not a postgresql expert, but i think you need select into

Comment: In SqlServer, you would use `DECLARE @indiaCountry int` (note the added @) - could that be the same in postgres? (still, the next line wouldn't make sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as though id is a serial column in your countries table, getting automatically generated, and you need to find out what this value is, before inserting into cities.

In PostgreSQL a serial column is just convenient syntax for a `sequence`. To find out the last value added to the `sequence` we use the `currval` function.  Unfortunately the `sequence` name is a generated name (there are rules), so it is easiest in addition to use another helper function `pg_get_serial_sequence`.

Putting all this together, what you can do in your case is the following:

```
INSERT INTO countries(description) VALUES('asdf');

INSERT INTO cities 
SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('countries','id')), 1, 'abc';
```

Note that `currval` is session safe.  Even if there are concurrent insertions, it will return the value from the insert within your session.

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses SQL Server-like syntax that is not supported in PostgreSQL.
You may use a [Data-Modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) like this:

```sql
with t as
(
 INSERT INTO COUNTRIES (description) VALUES('asdf') returning id
)
insert into cities select id, 1, 'abc' from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

In postgresql you can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO cities VALUES ((SELECT id FROM COUNTRIES WHERE description = 'asdf'), 1 , 'abc');
```

Or if you must use variables, you could use PL/pgSQL within anonymous block or a function. An example with anonymous block:

```
do $$ 
declare
  indiaCountry int;
begin
   SELECT id INTO indiaCountry FROM COUNTRIES WHERE description = 'asdf';
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES (indiaCountry, 1 , 'abc');
end $$;
```

Documentation for anonymous block: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html

Or you could skip the select statement and do this:

```
do $$ 
declare
  indiaCountry int;
begin
   INSERT INTO COUNTRIES (description) VALUES('asdf') RETURNING id INTO indiaCountry;
   INSERT INTO cities VALUES (indiaCountry, 1 , 'abc');
end $$;
```